# Confusion when using continuity of the $\Phi$ function for convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose that $X\sim N(0, 1)$. Then $P(X<2)=\Phi(2)$. Suppose now that $Y_n$ is a sequence of random variables so that $Y_n\xrightarrow{p} 2$. I think that the following statement holds
$$P(X<Y_n)\rightarrow P(X<2)$$

**Proof**: Since $\Phi$ is continuous, apply it to two sides of $Y_n\xrightarrow{p} 2$, leading
$$\Phi(Y_n) \xrightarrow{p} \Phi(2)$$
By definition of $\Phi$, it follows that
$$P(X<Y_n)\xrightarrow{p} P(X<2)$$
Note: convergence of a sequence of real numbers.

I am now confused.

1. Can I write $P(X<Y_n)=\Phi(Y_n)$?
2. Can I just simply throw $p$ away in the last statement because it involves only real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. the left side is  a number and right side is a random variable.
2. $P(X<Y_n)\xrightarrow{p} P(X<2)$ does not even make sense. $\xrightarrow{p} $ is for random variables, not for constants. But if you treat constants as r.v's, yes, you can drop the $p$ above the arrow.

Here is a valid proof of the statement:
$$P(X<Y_n) \leq P(X<2+\epsilon)+P(Y_n >2+\epsilon) \to \Phi (2+\epsilon)+0$$ and

$$P(X<2-\epsilon) \leq P(Y_n<2-\epsilon)+P(X<Y_n) .$$ So $$P(X<Y_n)\geq P(X<2-\epsilon)-P(Y_n<2-\epsilon) \to \Phi (2-\epsilon)-0.$$ Now finish the proof using continuity of $\Phi$.

Comment: Thank for your excellent proof. I do not know the trick that you introduce $2+\varepsilon$ and $2-\varepsilon$. For the inequalities, I took me some time to understand but it is a useful weapon. Based on your brief proof, I have made a complete one. If you have time, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

**Based on the excellent proof given by @Kavi**, I present here a complete version.

Take arbitrarily an $\varepsilon>0$, we need to show that there exist $n_0$ so that $\forall n>n_0$, we have $|P(X<Y_n)- P(X<2)|<\varepsilon$.

Let $f(y)=\Phi(2+y)-\Phi(2-y)$. Since  $\Phi()$ is continuous, $f(y)$ is continuous. Hence, there exist $\delta>0$ so that $|f({\delta})-f(0)|<\varepsilon/2$, which leads to
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|\Phi(2+\delta)-\Phi(2-\delta)-\left(\Phi(2+0)-\Phi(2-0)\right)|<\varepsilon/2\Rightarrow |\Phi(2+\delta)-\Phi(2-\delta)| <\varepsilon/2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Note that $\Phi$ is monotonically increasing, we then have
$$0< \Phi(2+\delta)-\Phi(2-\delta) <\varepsilon/2$$

Because $Y_n\xrightarrow{p} 2$, it follows that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }P(|Y_n-2|\geq \gamma)=0$ $\forall \gamma>0$. In particular, $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }P(|Y_n-2|\geq \delta)=0$. Thus, there exists $n_0$ so that for all $n>n_0$, $P(|Y_n-2|\geq \delta)<\varepsilon/4$.

I now prove that $\forall n>n_0$, we have $|P(X<Y_n)-P(X<2)|<\varepsilon$.

Take arbitrarily an $n>n_0$. Note that if event $\{X<Y_n\}$ occurs then at least one of the two following events occurs: $\{X<2+\delta\}$ and $\{Y_n>2+\delta\}$ (Otherwise, their complements, i.e., $\{X\geq 2+\delta\}$ and $\{Y_n\leq 2+\delta\}$, occur, which leads to the concurrence of $\{X\geq Y_n\}$, a contradiction). Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P\left(X<Y_n\right)&\leq P\left(\{X<2+\delta\}\cup\{Y_n>2+\delta\}\right)\leq P\left(X<2+\delta\right) + P\left(Y_n>2+\delta\right)\\
&<\Phi\left(2+\delta\right)+ \varepsilon/4
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
(Since $P\left(Y_n>2+\delta\right) + P\left(Y_n<2-\delta\right)=P\left(|Y_n-2|>\delta\right)<\varepsilon/4$)

Using a similar argument, we have:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&P\left(X<2-\delta\right)\leq P\left(\{X<Y_n\}\cup\{Y_n<2-\delta\}\right)\leq P\left(X<Y_n\right) + P\left(Y_n<2-\delta\right)\\
&\Rightarrow P\left(X<Y_n\right) \geq P\left(X<2-\delta\right) - P\left(Y_n<2-\delta\right)>\Phi(2-\delta)-\varepsilon/4\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
\Phi(2-\delta)-\varepsilon/4 < P\left(X<Y_n\right)< \Phi\left(2+\delta\right)+ \varepsilon/4
\end{equation}
We also have
\begin{equation}
\Phi(2-\delta)-\varepsilon/4 < \Phi(2)=P\left(X<2\right) < \Phi\left(2+\delta\right)+ \varepsilon/4
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
|P(X<Y_n)- P(X<2)|< \Phi\left(2+\delta\right)+ \varepsilon/4 - \left(\Phi(2-\delta)-\varepsilon/4\right)<\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/4+\varepsilon/4=\varepsilon.
\end{equation}